# Specifying the seed for a random number in Omnet++

Tags: simulation, omnet++

Just wondering if anyone knows how to manually specify the seed for a distribution in Omnet++. For example, with the omnetpp.ini file as follows:

```
[Config PacketProject]
network = PacketProject
**.stopTime = 5000s
PacketProject.webServer.interArrivalTime = exponential(0.025s)"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Click on the INI file. Dont use the source mode view, just stay on the form mode view.

Click on the left on "Random Numbers". There you can specify the seed. After that you can switch to source mode view and see what was added there.

Answer (score 1):

A distribution uses a RNG with a seed to generate random values in according to the distribution chosen.
Obviously, changing the seed, you will have different values generated.
By default Omnet++ defines only one RNG with one seed associated to it. 
You can define a seed-**set** associated to a RNG (note the word set) in the file omnet.ini in this way:

```
repeat = number_of_repetition
seed-set = ${repetition}
```

Now, automatically, omnet will associate this set of seed to your RNG (as a result your simulation will be repeated number_of_repetition times).

You can also define multiple RNGs in the file omnet.ini in this way:

```
num-rngs = number_of_RNGs
```

Now, automatically, omnet will associate a set of seed to each RNG that you have defined.
Suppose that you have defined 2 RNGs; you can associate a RNG to a distribution in the file omnet.ini in this way:

```
PacketProject.webServer.interArrivalTime = exponential(0.025s, 0)
```

Note the second argument, that specifies the number of the RNG chosen.

Answer (score 0):

On the OMNeT++ website there is [this article](https://omnetpp.org/news/2004/10/31/sp-336207964.html) that explains how to set the random number generator algorithms and how to seeding the RNGs.

Comment: Thanks for adding that link! Helped me solve an issue on INET 4.2.5